# magento 2.4.3 Custom theme "Required parameter theme_dir was not passed"

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.4, parent-child-theme, magento2.4.3

I'm trying to create custom theme in my magento 2.4.3. I m getting error "" have written like this below.

> **1 exception(s):
> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed**

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "swissup/theme-frontend-absolutechild",
    "description": "N/A",
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "version": "100.4.3",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.3.0||~7.4.0",
        "swissup/theme-frontend-absolute": "1.5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/Swissup/absolutechild', __DIR__);
```

**theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>Absolute child</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Swissup/absolute</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
 </theme>
```

After creating folder(web,layout). I ran commands in following order.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush
```

This is my error "****1 exception(s):

> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed****"

Kindly can anyone help me this please?

Comment: parent theme is exist?

Comment: yes, blank theme is the absolute theme!

Comment: I have installed absolute theme from magento marketplace!